# How to make a timer text box in JavaScript that show how long is user online?

Tags: javascript, timer

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to make an simple program that count how long is a user online on the website with a simple text box.

```js
var sec=0; 
function showtime(){ 
    box.value=sec; 
    sec+=1; 
    if sec<=60 ("showtime()",1000); 
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="showtime()"> 
<input type=text name=box size=30> 
</body>
```

Comment: There are scripts for this readily available all over the internet. Also look at how to use . ALso lots of tutorials around for setting something like this up. Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: You can create timestamp when you open the page use setInterval to create new timestamp every second substract the times and you will get differents in miliseconds that you can convert to time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
var count = 0;
function myFunction(){
 count++;
a[0].value = count;
}
setInterval(myFunction,1000)
```

```html
<input type='text' value='' name='box' size='30' onload='myFunction()' >
```

Comment: according to your question i post this solution code